# How can I pass regular functions that involve selenium into a pytest within a class?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pytest

Beginner here! I have some basic functions that include some selenium code I want to reuse. However, I am unsure as to how I can incorporate this code as my driver is initialized inside a fixture. How can I approach this?

Here is my conftest.py code

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def setup(request):
    options = Options()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

    request.cls.driver = driver

    driver.get(url)
    driver.maximize_window()
    pyautogui.typewrite(username)
    pyautogui.press('tab')
    pyautogui.typewrite(password)
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    time.sleep(3)

    yield

    driver.quit()



@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class BaseTest:
    pass
```

here is a small sample of my test.py code

```
class TestLandingPage(BaseTest):
        def test_profilenav(self):
        profile = self.driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,
                                      value="/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div/a[1]")

        if profile.is_displayed():
            profileDisplayed = "Profile Icon is displayed"
            print(profileDisplayed)
            buttonDisplayed.append(profileDisplayed)
        else:
            profileNotDisplayed = "Profile Icon is not displayed"
            print(profileNotDisplayed)
            buttonNotDisplayed.append(profileNotDisplayed)

        if profile.is_enabled():
            profileEnabled = "Profile button is enabled"
            print(profileEnabled)
            buttonEnabled.append(profileEnabled)
        else:
            profileDisabled = "Profile button is disabled"
            print(profileDisabled)
            buttonDisabled.append(profileDisabled)


        profile.click()
        profileClickAction = "Profile passed"
        print(profileClickAction)
        clickActionPassed.append(profileClickAction)

        returnToHome()
        profileIcon()
```

and here is are the functions I would like to use within my pytest code, but don't know where to put/how to fit in

```
def returnToHome():
    time.sleep(2)
    logo = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='[alt="banner"]')
    if logo.is_displayed():
       print("Logo return to home is displayed")
    else:
        print("Logo return to home is not displayed")
    logo.click()
    time.sleep(2)


def profileIcon():
    profileIcon = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]")
    if profileIcon.is_displayed():
        print("Profile Icon button is displayed")
    else:
        print("Profile Icon button is not displayed")
    profileIcon.click()
    print("Profile Icon passed")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase as your `pytest` + `selenium` framework. There are examples of the page object model, where the `driver` (via `sb.driver`) is passed to methods that need it. Eg. The script below runs with `pytest` once you have `seleniumbase` installed.

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
BaseCase.main(__name__, __file__)

class LoginPage:
    def login_to_swag_labs(self, sb, username):
        sb.open("https://www.saucedemo.com")
        sb.type("#user-name", username)
        sb.type("#password", "secret_sauce")
        sb.click('input[type="submit"]')

class MyTests(BaseCase):
    def test_swag_labs_login(self):
        LoginPage().login_to_swag_labs(self, "standard_user")
        self.assert_element("div.inventory_list")
        self.assert_element('div:contains("Sauce Labs Backpack")')
```

Additionally, there is an `sb` fixture format. Example:

```py
import pytest
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
BaseCase.main(__name__, __file__)

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("sb")
class Test_UseFixtures:
    def test_usefixtures_on_class(self):
        sb = self.sb
        sb.open("seleniumbase.io/simple/login")
        sb.type("#username", "demo_user")
        sb.type("#password", "secret_pass")
        sb.click('a:contains("Sign in")')
        sb.assert_exact_text("Welcome!", "h1")
        sb.assert_element("img#image1")
        sb.highlight("#image1")
        sb.click_link("Sign out")
        sb.assert_text("signed out", "#top_message")
```

After combining that fixture format with the page object model, that could look something like this:

```py
import pytest
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
BaseCase.main(__name__, __file__)

class LoginPage:
    def login_to_swag_labs(self, sb, username):
        sb.open("https://www.saucedemo.com")
        sb.type("#user-name", username)
        sb.type("#password", "secret_sauce")
        sb.click('input[type="submit"]')

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("sb")
class Test_UseFixtures:
    def test_usefixtures_on_class(self):
        sb = self.sb
        LoginPage().login_to_swag_labs(sb, "standard_user")
        sb.assert_element("div.inventory_list")
        sb.assert_element('div:contains("Sauce Labs Backpack")')
```